# The SELECT statement includes a reserved word or an argument name that is misspelled or missing, or the punctuation is incorrect. (Error 3141)

Tags: sql, ms-access

I get this error for the SQL statement below, and I really do not know where to search for the error. I am a newbie in SQL for Access.

```
SELECT [belfiusbonussavings].ID, [belfiusbonussavings].jaar, [belfiusbonussavings].maand, [belfiusbonussavings].dag, [belfiusbonussavings].debet, [belfiusbonussavings].credit, [belfiusbonussavings].datum, [belfiusbonussavings].comment, [belfiusbonussavings].verschil,
FROM [belfiusbonussavings]
 (SELECT Sum(verschil) FROM [belfiusbonussavings] as OD WHERE OD.ID <= [belfiusbonussavings].ID) AS saldobedrag
FROM [belfiusbonussavings]
ORDER BY [belfiusbonussavings].[ID], [belfiusbonussavings].[jaar], [belfiusbonussavings].[maand], [belfiusbonussavings].[dag];
```

Comment: There is a comma right before `FROM`. And you are missing commas in other spots. Try structuring your code a bit and see where they are

Comment: Apparently, did not use the Access query build to structure this SQL. Can't have two FROM clauses in the outer SQL. Remove the first `FROM [belfiusbonussavings]` and leave the commas.

Comment: Thanks for the answers, they helped very well. Problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems with this query and you can see them if you format it better, for example:

```sql
SELECT 
    [belfiusbonussavings].ID, 
    [belfiusbonussavings].jaar, 
    [belfiusbonussavings].maand, 
    [belfiusbonussavings].dag, 
    [belfiusbonussavings].debet, 
    [belfiusbonussavings].credit, 
    [belfiusbonussavings].datum, 
    [belfiusbonussavings].comment, 
    [belfiusbonussavings].verschil,       <-- 1ST trouble (extra comma)
FROM [belfiusbonussavings]                <-- 2nd trouble (missing comma)
    (
        SELECT 
            Sum(verschil) 
        FROM [belfiusbonussavings] as OD 
        WHERE OD.ID <= [belfiusbonussavings].ID
    ) AS saldobedrag
FROM [belfiusbonussavings]
ORDER BY [belfiusbonussavings].[ID], [belfiusbonussavings].[jaar], [belfiusbonussavings].[maand], [belfiusbonussavings].[dag];
```

Other issues include:

- Too many FROMs
- `saldobedrag` is not used

Comment: Thanks for the answers, they helped very well. Problem solved.